# whether 'thanks for doing something' can only be used for stuff in the past

Tags: word-choice

'thanks for coming', 'thanks for listening' etc are usually used at the end of the meetings. Can they ever be used at the beginning rather than the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can definitely be used at the beginning; I have had it used that way many times.

Comment: At the start of a phone call, I find it a bit weird to say 'thanks for calling me' upfront, as it sounds to end the call. Any comment on this?

Comment: @feynman If someone called me back, it’d sound natural to greet the person with “Thanks for returning my call.” The more senior the caller or meeting attendees are, the more politeness and formality are warranted.